# search on cck created content type on Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, cck

I am developing a website with a specific content type in Drupal: I use CCK to define this content type.

I also need an advanced search form to give the site visitors doing their search based on any fields of this content type. but i have no idea about implementing it.

Would someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

CCK provides filters to the Views module, so you could use a view to at least come close to what you want (I don't know if a full text search is possible using this approach).

drupal.org itself uses [Apache Solr Search Intergration](http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr). Apache Solr Search Intergration requires [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). If you do not do not have the means to set up Apache Solr (or do not want to for some other reasons), you can use an instance of Apache Solr provided by Acquia (called acquia search).